# ASP.NET MVC5 identity linking local accounts with external accounts (social claims) during user registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5

I’m using External Login with ASP.Net Identity.

Everything works good with standard functionality. I am trying to extend the identity to use the claims to login into the application.

I am was able to added the external provider. Now i am trying link the multiple external providers.

That being said, if user has already a local account and if the same user try to login with Google (or other provider) the Account controller external callback method does not identify the local user (code block from the below default codes "SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);" gives SignInStatus.Failure. ) and redirect the user to register with the email from the claim.

If the user clicks the **register button** it returns and error "user exists". How ever,If user logs in with the local account and do the same thing with to with Managelogins action method in Manage controller   – The accounts are linked.

I am trying to achieve the same thing with register action without having the user logging in with the local account and have automatic linking the social provider at first time or redirect the user to link the accounts.

default code with asp.net mvc5 scaffolding. I tried all the different options and you could see in the commented code in method. But nothing worked.

```
// GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        //var externalLoginInfo = await _signInManager.AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        //if (externalLoginInfo == null)
        //{
        //    return RedirectToAction("Index", "SignIn");
        //}

        //var u = SignInManager.UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);
        //// Check if the user with this external login provider already has a login
        //if (await SignInManager.UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login) != null) 
        //    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");

        //await SignInManager.UserManager.AddLoginAsync(HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity.GetUserId<string>(), loginInfo.Login);

        ////return RedirectToAction("Index", "Social");

        //// Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: true);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you found the answer to this question?  I encountered this same situation today.

Comment: Yes, I was able to figure it out. I will post the resolution soon.

Comment: The easiest fix is, If the user already have a local account  and want to link the external provider.Then User can login into the app with the local credentials and go to manage and link their account with  external provider. This is the same approach that Microsoft uses.

Comment: If the user don't have local account then new account can be created by using the external providers. This is one of best security practices, so that application wont leak if the account exits in the app.